# Complex Json Mapping in Spring with RestTemplate

Tags: java, json, spring, resttemplate

I am trying to map a jsonResponse with my Java entity class. The json response looks as follow

```
   "classResults":{
      "classSuggestion":[
          "classA",
          {
            "section":"section c"
          }
      ]
    }
```

My Java Class for mapping might looks something like this. I will have an object of ClassSuggestion in order to map classSuggestion object. However how would the classSuggestion be to hold the json data as above ?

```
public class ClassResults {

   ClassSuggestion classSuggestion

}
```

How would my ClassSuggestion be ?

```
public class ClassSuggestion {

   String classes
   String section
}
```

How do I map this to a Java Class or data type ?

Comment: So, in short, you want a union type? Would it be possible to wrap `"classA"` in an object similar to `{ "section":"section c" }` (do you have control over the JSON API)? How many strings and `section` objects can there be?

Comment: I don't have control over the JSON API, thats owned by different team. I was able to deserialize using custom deserializer which I was trying to avoid initially for the ease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by writing a custom deserializer:

```
class ClassSuggestionDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Employee> {

   @Override
   public Map<String, String> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
      ObjectCodec codec = jp.getCodec();
      TreeNode node = codec.readTree(jp);
      JsonNode classResults = node.get("classResults");
      // and finally iterating through the classResults to get string values
   }
}
```

Meanwhile on the data class,used JsonDeserialize using the custom deserializer.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using=ClassSuggestionDeserializer.class)
public class ClassSuggestion {

   Map<String, String> classResults;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Data // lombok
public class ClassResults {
   private List<ClassSuggestion> classSuggestion; // mapped from array
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ClassSuggestion {
   private String classes;
   private String section;
   public ClassSuggestion(String classes) {
     this.classes = classes; //Handle string "classA"
   }
}
```